# jQuery maphilight change color on the fly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dictionary, canvas

I'm using this plugin http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/

But can't figure out, how to change color on the fly.
It uses metadata plugin, and does it via class directive, but changes don't apply on fly.

e.g.

```
class="{stroke:false,fillColor:'000000',fillOpacity:1,alwaysOn:true}"
```

and now I want to change color:

```
class="{stroke:false,fillColor:'00ffff',fillOpacity:1,alwaysOn:true}"
```

Comment: Do you have a sample setup somewhere to test with? Because in reading the site documentation it seems like it should be pretty straightforward because you can pass options to the highlight function.

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/

Comment: Yes, but maphilight() should be apply to root map element, not to area. And changing class with appropriate metadata and recalling maphilight() doesn't have any effect.

Comment: You can try to change color on fly in this page via JS Console
http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found that using canvas resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

you need this plugin to include

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*
 * Metadata - jQuery plugin for parsing metadata from elements
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 John Resig, Yehuda Katz, J�örn Zaefferer, Paul McLanahan
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Revision: $Id: jquery.metadata.js 3620 2007-10-10 20:55:38Z pmclanahan $
 *
 */
(function($){$.extend({metadata:{defaults:{type:'class',name:'metadata',cre:/({.*})/,single:'metadata'},setType:function(type,name){this.defaults.type=type;this.defaults.name=name;},get:function(elem,opts){var settings=$.extend({},this.defaults,opts);if(!settings.single.length)settings.single='metadata';var data=$.data(elem,settings.single);if(data)return data;data="{}";if(settings.type=="class"){var m=settings.cre.exec(elem.className);if(m)data=m[1];}else if(settings.type=="elem"){if(!elem.getElementsByTagName)return;var e=elem.getElementsByTagName(settings.name);if(e.length)data=$.trim(e[0].innerHTML);}else if(elem.getAttribute!=undefined){var attr=elem.getAttribute(settings.name);if(attr)data=attr;}if(data.indexOf('{')<0)data="{"+data+"}";data=eval("("+data+")");$.data(elem,settings.single,data);return data;}}});$.fn.metadata=function(opts){return $.metadata.get(this[0],opts);};})(jQuery);</script>
```